# Is there a way to quickly take two photos at different apertures?

Tags: aperture, bracketing

I would sometimes like to take two shots quickly, at different apertures, such as f/2.8 and f/4, but with the same exposure value (EV). Is there a way to do this with the Sony NEX-5R?

In some situations, I don't have time to fiddle with the settings and then wait a couple of seconds to avoid camera shake, and then take the second shot -- whatever I'm trying to capture would have passed by then. An example is taking a long exposure photo of a passing train at night. By the time I adjust the aperture and wait for camera shake to stop, the train would have passed. So, I wanted to check if there's some way to set this up ahead of time, and then trigger a rapid sequence of shots when the train comes.

Note: I don't think exposure bracketing will help here, since it will take a sequence of photos with a different EV value. Whereas I want a sequence of photos that are equally bright or dark, but shot with different apertures (and correspondingly shorter or longer shutter speeds).

Comment: In other words, you want to bracket the aperture, not bracket the exposure *via* aperture changes.

Comment: I don't know if you intended that as a question to me, or as a clarification to other readers. In case it's a question, the answer is: yes, that's exactly what I want to do. Thanks.

Comment: A clarification. It might also be called "[Depth of Field Bracketing](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12553/what-is-depth-of-field-bracketing)". I'm not aware of any camera which has an automated function to do it, though.

Comment: Ah, yes, I had read about DoF bracketing, but I'd ignored it, since I am not primarily interested in depth of field, but I guess that it's the same technique in any case.

Comment: Probably of no actual use, but there's a [nex-hack.info website](http://www.nex-hack.info/), where it looks like they're taking the first steps towards doing Magic Lantern like things for NEX/Alpha.

Comment: Thanks, inkista. This is good information though personally I'm not one to hack / root my devices. In any case, thanks for the information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this can be done with a script on a tethered laptop.
(but I am curious about the use of this kind of different DOF.)

Comment: I won't be able to take a laptop with me when I go out to take photos. Neither can the Sony NEX-5R be tethered to a laptop as far as I know. To answer your question of what I plan to use this for, I want to shoot passing trains at different apertures, which implies different shutter speeds. As you know, long shutter speeds cause moving objects to blur more. I don't use shutter speed priority mode because I don't have a particular shutter speed (like 1s) in mind. I want to try the aperture at which my lens is sharpest, and wide open. I think in terms of aperture, not shutter speed.