# How to achieve sharpness on image

Tags: nikon, 50mm, nikon-d5300

I'm new to photography and got my new [50mm Nikkor f1.8g](http://www.nikon.fr/fr_FR/product/nikkor-lenses/auto-focus-lenses/fx/single-focal-length/af-s-nikkor-50mm-f-1-8g) for my DX camera D5300.

I've taken first Portrait photoshoot of my friend in an outdoor park which looked nice on my camera screen. But when I move it to my computer, I could see the images were not sharp. I was inspired by many people's Portrait images with 50mm which thought I could replicate the same. But I assume I'm making some mistakes which can't identify myself.

I've taken various images of a subject with distinct settings and attached for your reference. Please advise me: what am I doing wrong?

Some info:

- I used a tripod
- All images are cropped 100%
- Distance from subject to camera: 2 meters
- no post-processing

You can see the grain on all images. Please help
[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you shooting RAW/JPG? I also don't understand two apparently conflicting pieces of information... distance 2m & 100% crop. At 2m that model would be tiny in the frame & so would require a heavy crop to re-frame as your posted shots. Why not get closer to your subject; that lens ought to be OK at 20cm on a small subject like that.

Comment: @Tetsujin All were Raw and converted into JPEG to upload here. Actually i used my friend with distance of 2m and results were not sharpen. So i replicated with this tiny object. This car size would equalise person's eye in portraiture. So i would like to know how to get that shot

Comment: Sharpness decreases with widening aperture, that lens is at its sharpest at around f8-10

Comment: @DigitalLightcraft is there any way to achieve sharpness at wide?? no cheat way to turn it ?? like flash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As highlighted in the comment, all other things being equal, the sharpness of a lens depends only on the aperture. Of course, you need to use the suggestion of [Why are my photos not crisp?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/50006/why-are-my-photos-not-crisp) to use the most of what you have.

As mentioned in this question ([Is there a difference in sharpness between aperture stops?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/25360/is-there-a-difference-in-sharpness-between-aperture-stops/25366#25366)), lenses are soft (low sharpness) at their maximum aperture and sharpness increases as you stop down your lens (=as you are using a smaller aperture, for example from f/2.8 to f/8).

However, due to diffraction limit ([What is a "diffraction limit"?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/8304/what-is-a-diffraction-limit)), you can stop a lens indefinitely and after a point, sharpness decreases again (example : [Why isn't this portrait taken at f/29 sharp?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/65646/why-isnt-this-portrait-taken-at-f-29-sharp)).

**Single shot**

If you want to have the sharpest image your lens can deliver with a single shot, you might want to look at charts made by people reviewing lens. For example, for your lens, you will find result such as [this one](http://www.photozone.de/nikon_ff/631-nikkorafs5018ff) (from [www.photozone.de](http://www.photozone.de/nikon_ff/631-nikkorafs5018ff)) :

[image: Nikkor AF-S 50mm f/1.8 G MTF]

This chart gives the MTF of your lens (see [How do I interpret an MTF Chart?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1686/how-do-i-interpret-an-mtf-chart)): the higher score, the better the resolution. So with your lens, the *best* settings should be around f/5.6 for a maximum sharpness.

Of course, with a given aperture and if your want to keep the same distance to your subject, the depth of field will be fixed too (look at [What is aperture, and how does it affect my photographs?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/49/what-is-aperture-and-how-does-it-affect-my-photographs) and [What exactly determines depth of field?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/9624/what-exactly-determines-depth-of-field)).

With an aperture of f/5.6, a focal length of 50mm and a distance to your subject of 2 meters, the DoF will be about (results from http://dofsimulator.net/en/), the DoF will be about 35cm (from 16cm in front of your focus point to 19cm after it). It changes to 50cm at f/8.

If the DoF is too shallow for your taste, you can use another technique.

**Multiple Shoot**

If you really want the best sharpness on all your object (or your scene), you can combine multiple images taken with the *best* aperture, each taken with a different point of focus. This is called "DoF stacking" and you can find more info here:

- [What is Depth Of Field bracketing?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12553/what-is-depth-of-field-bracketing)
- [What are the best practices for DOF stacking?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/667/what-are-the-best-practices-for-dof-stacking)

For a portrait, however (=moving person in the scene), I doubt DoF stacking is a viable solution (probably a lot of ghost effects).